Karate UI - how to select an option in a dynamic dropdown list
my test, select commune, clicking on the option does not work
test
@TEST2
Scenario: Validación de factibilidad Internet Hogar
# Ingresar a la página web wom.cl
Given match driver.title == 'WOM | Planes Móviles, Prepago e Internet Hogar al mejor precio'
# Seleccionar Menú Hogar -> Internet Hogar
When waitFor("//a[@class='h-bt-sub-mnu']//span[contains(text(),'Hogar')]").click()
And waitFor("//span[normalize-space()='Internet Hogar']").click()
* delay(10000)
Then match driver.title == 'Internet Hogar | Planes en oferta | Contrata con descuentos'

# Verificar factibilidad exitosa ingresando Región, Comuna y calle y número
* scroll("//h2[contains(text(),'Verifica la factibilidad de Internet Hogar WOM en ')]")
And match text("//h2[contains(text(),'Verifica la factibilidad de Internet Hogar WOM en ')]") == 'Verifica la factibilidad de Internet Hogar WOM en tu barrio'
* delay(5000)

# seleccionar region


# seleccionar comuna
* waitFor("#city_in_plp").click()
* delay(10000)
* scroll("//div[@class='item' and contains(text(),'LO ESPEJO')]")
* waitForText("//div[@class='item' and contains(text(),'LO ESPEJO')]", "LO ESPEJO")
* click("//div[@class='item' and contains(text(),'LO ESPEJO')]")
* delay(5000)

I wanted to click and according to the report, I managed to do so, but it did not perform the action.

see if the docs help else impossible to help without access to your app: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#drop-downs

Background: Configuracion
* configure driver = {type: 'chrome', highlight: false}
* driver 'https://wom.cl/'
* maximize()
